# Typing in a Combobox to filter for selection in a subform grid

Tags: combobox, filtering

I have a form in ms access 2016 with a subform in datagrid view.  I have a column that is a combobox and I am filtering the values as you type.  It works for the first selection, but when after I make my selection and I want to either go to the next record and make another selection or change the selection I made in my current row, all the values disappear and are blank.  This is my code:

```
Option Compare Database
Private Const RecordSQL As String = "SELECT ConID, ItemNo, Description FROM Consignment"

Public Sub FilterComboAsYouType(combo As ComboBox, defaultSQL As String, lookupField As String)
    Dim strSQL As String
    If Len(combo.Text) > 0 Then
        strSQL = defaultSQL & " WHERE " & lookupField & " LIKE '*" & combo.Text & "*'"
    Else
        strSQL = defaultSQL    'This is the default row source of combo box
    End If
    combo.RowSource = strSQL
    combo.Dropdown
End Sub


Private Sub Select_Item_AfterUpdate()
    'reset dropdown list
    
    Select_Item.RowSource = RecordSQL
    Select_Item.Requery
    Select_Item.Dropdown
    Select_Item.SetFocus
    

    End Sub

Private Sub Select_Item_Change()
    
    FilterComboAsYouType Me.Select_Item, RecordSQL, "Description"
    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching and playing with code, I found this solution which I modified to my application.  This code below worked for what I needed:

```
''' 

Option Compare Database

Private Const RecordSQL As String = "SELECT ConID, ItemNo, Description FROM Consignment"

Public Sub FilterComboAsYouType(Filter As Boolean)
    Dim strSQL As String
    
    strSQL = RecordSQL    'This is the default row source of combo box
    Me.Select_Item.RowSource = strSQL
    'Me.Select_Item.Requery
    
    DoEvents
    If Filter Then
        DoEvents
        strSQL = RecordSQL & " WHERE Description LIKE '*" & Me.Select_Item.Text & "*'"
        Me.Select_Item.RowSource = strSQL
        'Me.Select_Item.Requery
        Me.Select_Item.Dropdown
        'Forms![PurchaseOrders]![PO_Con Subform]!Select_Item.Refresh
        'Forms![PurchaseOrders]![PO_Con Subform].Refresh
        'Me.Repaint
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Form_Load()
    FilterComboAsYouType False
End Sub

Private Sub Select_Item_AfterUpdate()
    
    FilterComboAsYouType False
    
    'Set Focus on Mainform Control
    'Me.Parent.Text17.SetFocus
    'Me.PoQty.SetFocus
    

End Sub

Private Sub Select_Item_Change()
    
    FilterComboAsYouType True

End Sub

Private Sub Select_Item_GotFocus()
    FilterComboAsYouType False
End Sub

Private Sub Select_Item_LostFocus()
    FilterComboAsYouType False
End Sub

Private Sub txtSerial_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    Me.Select_Item.SetFocus
    FilterComboAsYouType True
    'DoEvents
    Me.Select_Item.Dropdown
End Sub

'''
```